# A paper by W. Ljunggren

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I am looking for the following paper by Ljunggren, Wilhelm: "Zur Theorie der Gleichung $x^2 + 1 = Dy^4$", Avh. Norske Vid. Akad. Oslo. I., 1942 (5): 27

The main result of this paper which I am interested in is that the solutions in positive integers of the equation $x^2 + 1 = 2y^4$ are $(1,1), (239,13)$, so a reference summarizing Ljunggren's proof would be welcome as well.

Comment: [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532580/original-proof-of-ljunggrens-equation#comment3121516_1532580) says "The original proof uses a very delicate variant of Skolem's p-adic method".

Comment: Also user whose name resembles Jose Stgo. has a post on MathOverflow which summarizes a related paper and may have a link to your paper or near to your paper of interest.  So search MathOverflow for It. Gerhard "You're In The Right Place". Paseman, 2020.06.11.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I'll find it.

Comment: An idea that has worked for me is to ask for a copy to someone who has recently cited the article in question. Many people (me included) keep scanned copies of articles which are impossible to find online.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

Two papers that simplify Ljunggren's proof:

[An Elementary Proof for Ljunggren Equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03011) (2017)

[Simplifying the Solution of Ljunggren's Equation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81969969.pdf) (1991)

Comment: I believe that the first paper has an error, specifically the claim at the bottom of page 2 that if (c,b,13k) is a Pythagorean triple then b/c is either 5/12 or 12/5. In any case, I am aware of other proofs but I am interested specifically in the orginal proof. I should probably have emphasized that in the original question.

Comment: $(16,63,65)$, $b/c=16/63$.